# SPFX Property Pane property Undefined

Tags: spfx-webparts, spfx-custom-property-pane

I have added a PropertyPaneSlider control to an spfx web part. The control displays on the page and appears to be configured correctly.

I want to get the value of the control from the properties collection in my code but it is undefined. Below is the code in my WebpPart.ts file. What am I doing wrong?

```
export interface INewsViewerWebPartProps {
  sliderProperty: any;
}

export default class NewsViewerWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<INewsViewerWebPartProps> {        
  private _isDarkTheme: boolean = false;
  private _environmentMessage: string = '';
    
  public render(): void {
      const element: React.ReactElement<INewsViewerProps> = React.createElement(
          NewsViewer,
          {
            sliderProperty: this.properties.sliderProperty,
            isDarkTheme: this._isDarkTheme,
            environmentMessage: this._environmentMessage,
            hasTeamsContext: !!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams,
            userDisplayName: this.context.pageContext.user.displayName
          }
        );
    
      ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
}

protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneSlider('sliderProperty', {
                  label: "Max Pages",
                  min: 4,
                  max: 50,
                  value: 8,
                  showValue: true,
                  step: 1
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

your property should be in your webpart.manifest.json

```
 "preconfiguredEntries": [{
     "groupId": "5c03119e-3074-46fd-976b-c60198311f70", // Advanced
     "group": { "default": "Advanced" },
     "title": { "default": "testOnly" },
     "description": { "default": "testOnly description" },
     "officeFabricIconFontName": "Page",
     "properties": {
       "description": "testOnly",
       "sliderProperty": "1"
     }   }]
```

And in your interface

```
export interface INewsViewerWebPartProps {
  sliderProperty: number
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I don't recall seeing any mention of webpart.manifest.json in the doco I read

Comment: Please see this document for an example with more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/validate-web-part-property-values#add-the-listname-web-part-property